# SequelizeJS Using If/Else Statements with Date Field GetterMethods

Tags: javascript, momentjs, sequelize.js

I have a run into an interesting issue where I am using momentjs and the Sequelize getter definition to create a date range slug for my two date fields (e.g. 3/1/16 - 3/7/16). This logic works, but I have instances where a record in my database can be created without those fields being filled in and as a result left as null. In these instances, my records are displayed in my view with (1/1/1970 - 1/1/1970). I initially thought this was an issue with my view template setup, but then realized that it is momentjs populating a date range for the null values. As a result I was wondering if it was possible to create an if/else statement with my getter definition to basically not appear if a value for both fields is not present. My code below does not achieve this workflow. Any better way to do this?

Here is my if/else snippet:

```
if (startDate && endDate == null){
   return null;
} else {
   return momentStartDate + ' - ' + momentEndDate;
}
```

Here is my full model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var moment = require('moment');

var Discovery = sequelize.define('discovery', {
    discoveryId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'discovery_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    dataDateStart: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'data_date_start',
        allowNull: true,
        isDate: true
    },
    dataDateEnd: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'data_date_end',
        allowNull: true,
        isDate: true
    }
},

 {
    freezeTableName: true,
    getterMethods: {
        dataDateRangeSlug: function(){
            var startDate = new Date(this.getDataValue('dataDateStart')); 
            var momentStartDate = moment(startDate).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

            var endDate = new Date(this.getDataValue('dataDateEnd'));
            var momentEndDate = moment(endDate).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

           if (startDate && endDate == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            return momentStartDate + ' - ' + momentEndDate;
         }
        },
        dataDateStartSlug: function(){
            var startDate = new Date(this.getDataValue('dataDateStart')); 
            var momentStartDate = moment(startDate).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

            return momentStartDate;
        },
        dataDateEndSlug: function(){
            var endDate = new Date(this.getDataValue('dataDateEnd'));
            var momentEndDate = moment(endDate).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

            return momentEndDate;
        },
    },
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Discovery.belongsTo(db.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'}),
            Discovery.hasOne(db.DiscoverySource, {foreignKey: 'discovery_source_id'});
        }
    }
});
    return Discovery;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you replace your `dataDateRangeSlug` code into

```
dataDateRangeSlug: function() {
    if (this.getDataValue('dataDateStart') && this.getDataValue('dataDateEnd')) {
        var momentStartDate = moment(this.getDataValue('dataDateStart')).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        var momentEndDate = moment(this.getDataValue('dataDateEnd')).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

        return momentStartDate + ' - ' + momentEndDate;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

While I haven't tried running it myself, I believe this is what you're looking for